# Can a Keras CNN model build with 2 channel of 28x28 size image, predict real world images(RGB)?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I m building a CNN model with tensorflow Keras and the dataset available is in black and white.

I m using ImageDataGenerator available from keras.preprocessing.image api to convert image to array. By default it converts every image to 3 channel input. So will my model be able to predict real world image(colored imaged) if the trained image is in color and not black and white?

Also in ImageDataGenerator there is parameter named "color_mode" where it can take input as  "grayscale" and gives us 2d array to be used in model. If I go with this approach do I need to convert real world image into grayscale as well?

Answer (score 1):

The color space of the images you train should be the same as the color space of the images your application images.

If luminance is the the most important e.g. OCR, then training on gray scale images should produce a more efficient image. But if you are to recognize things that could appear in different colors, it may be interesting to use a color input.

If the color is not important and you train using 3-channel images, e.g. RGB, you will have to give examples in enough colors to avoid it to overfitting to the color. e.g you want to distinguish a car from a tree, you may end up with a  model that maps any green object to a tree and all the rest to cars.